# Query error to write migration with room database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I'm try to migrate my room database on my project and I write the query for the migration.

Add two new column on the existing table. Here is the code. **Is this Right?**

```
private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE pages ADD COLUMN sources TEXT NOT NULL default '')");
    }
};
```

Here is the AppDatabase code:

```
@Database(entities = {DayInfoEntity.class, UserEntryEntity.class, CycleInfoEntity.class, CycleInfoTempEntity.class, PagesEntity.class}, version = 2, exportSchema = true)
@TypeConverters({DateConverter.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE pages ADD COLUMN sources TEXT NOT NULL default ''");
        }
    };

    private static AppDatabase appDatabase;

    @VisibleForTesting
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "app_name";

    public abstract PagesDao pagesDao();

    private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> mIsDatabaseCreated = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (appDatabase == null) {
            synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
                if (appDatabase == null) {
                    appDatabase = buildDatabase(context.getApplicationContext());
   appDatabase.updateDatabaseCreated(context.getApplicationContext());
                }
            }
        }
        return appDatabase;
    }

    private static AppDatabase buildDatabase(final Context appContext) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .build();
    }

    private void updateDatabaseCreated(final Context context) {
        if (context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).exists()) {
            setDatabaseCreated();
        }
    }

    private void setDatabaseCreated() {
        mIsDatabaseCreated.postValue(true);
    }
}
```

When I'm try to run at that time I'm getting this error.

```
Migration didn't properly handle: pages.
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='pages', columns={help=Column{name='help', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, privacyPolicy=Column{name='privacyPolicy', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, legend=Column{name='legend', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, info=Column{name='info', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, backstory=Column{name='backstory', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, language=Column{name='language', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, termsConditions=Column{name='termsConditions', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, sources=Column{name='sources', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='pages', columns={help=Column{name='help', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, legend=Column{name='legend', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, privacyPolicy=Column{name='privacyPolicy', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, info=Column{name='info', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, language=Column{name='language', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, sources=Column{name='sources', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, termsConditions=Column{name='termsConditions', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Comment: Remove `)` from the query you have written. It should work fine.

Comment: Please check again...

Answer (score 0):

> SQLite does not support adding multiple columns to a table using a
>   single statement. To add multiple columns to a table, you must execute
>   multiple ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN statements.

https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-add-column/

Add for each column a seperate statement:

```
  database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE pages ADD COLUMN sources TEXT NOT NULL default '' ");
  database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE pages ADD COLUMN backstory TEXT NOT NULL default '' ");
```

Comment: Can you please give me example. Coz link not found

Comment: Please check my updated question coz as you told my try one by one I was done before and I get this error.

Comment: Did you update the entity class? You have to add there the new columns too.
      @ColumnInfo(name="sources")
      @NonNull
      private String sources;

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with the changes of the bellow code. Don't forgot to add this `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` in database file:

For more details please check this link and read it once. I know that's boring but must read. After reading details I know my mistake. :)

Here is the link - https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions

```
 private static AppDatabase buildDatabase(final Context appContext) {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() // ADD THIS WHILE YOU DOIGN MIGRATION
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: This will delete the old data in the table.